# What is the meaning of this sentence ..please explain this

Tags: sentence, questions

You’re right to be cautious---what is the meaning of this

Answer (score 1):

According to Oxford dictionary (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/):

***CAUTIOUS***

adjective (of a person)

careful to avoid potential problems or dangers

So the meaning of your sentence is:

"Your carefulness is a correct behavior."

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help the asker, but we expect a certain minimum amount of research on their part. It would be helpful if they could tell us the context and why it is they still don't understand the sentence after looking up _cautious_. Hence my close vote.